# How to get the results from nls

Tags: r, nls

My data are as follows:

```
df<-read.table (text=" cup size
12  30.76923077
13  38.46153846
14  53.84615385
15  76.92307692
16  92.30769231
17  100", header=TRUE)
```

I have used the following codes to get the results

```
y=as.vector(df$cup)
x=as.vector(df$size)
fit <- nls(1/y ~ 1 + exp(-b*(x-c)), start = list(b = 0.01, c = 12), alg = "plinear")
```

I want to extract values b, c, .lin separately
like this:

```
b= 0.01552
c= 5.98258
lin= 0.04887
```

I have used fit[[2]], but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
df<-read.table (text=" cup size
12  30.76923077
13  38.46153846
14  53.84615385
15  76.92307692
16  92.30769231
17  100", header=TRUE)

y=as.vector(df$cup)
x=as.vector(df$size)
fit <- nls(1/y ~ 1 + exp(-b*(x-c)), start = list(b = 0.01, c = 12), alg = "plinear")
myvector <- coef(fit)
b <- myvector[1]
c <- myvector[2]
lin <- myvector[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @user20650, `coef` is the function used to extract the values from the model.

If you refer to the [source code](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/blob/master/src/library/stats/R/nls.R) you'll see it's hidden in the `m` element in the function `getAllPars()`

```
fit$m$getAllPars()
         b          c       .lin 
0.01552340 5.98262729 0.04887368
```

Comment: Thank you for your help